# Insert item of a plist file into a ComboBox

Tags: vb.net, combobox, plist

I'm new on this site.

I am creating an application in vb.net ... Basically it's a kind of downloaders, that every time you open the app, it starts downloading a plist file, which is structured as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
<Dict>
<Key> Value 1 </key>
<Dict>
<Key> downloadlink </key>
<String> http://mysite/file.zip </string>
</Dict>
<Key> Value 2 </ ey>
<Dict>
<Key> downloadlink </ key>
<String> http://mysite/file2.zip </string>
</Dict>
</Dict>
</Plist>
```

I would like to read the contents of the plist file. I wish `Value 1` and `Value 2` were included in a `ComboBox`, and that will change a variable (`Dim dlllink as String = Nothing`) when the value of the `ComboBox` is changed, with what's written in the midst of the values ​​`<string>` and `</ string>`. How can I do? Someone can help me? Thanks in advance to all!

Comment: It *sounds like* you want the combo items to show the Keys (value 1) but when they click or select or something, your code uses the "string" items?  Where are you stuck?  Reading the XML, populating the CBO?  As is, this is vague and broad

Comment: I don't know about how to do it